# Apache ignite spring data save method transaction behaviour with map parameter

Tags: ignite

As per apache `ignite` spring data documentation, there are two method to save the data in `ignite` cache:

```
1. org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.IgniteRepository.save(key, vlaue)
```

and

```
2. org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.IgniteRepository.save(Map<ID, S> entities)
```

So, I just want to understand the 2nd method transaction behavior. Suppose we are going to save the 100 records by using the `save(Map<Id,S>)` method and due to some reason after 70 records there are some nodes go down. In this case, will it roll back all the 70 records?

Note: As per 1st method behavior, If we use `@Transaction` at method level then it will roll back the particular entity.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should read about the transaction mechanism used in Apache Ignite. It is very good described in articles presented here:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/transactions#section-two-phase-commit-2pc

The most interesting part for you is "Backup Node Failures" and "Primary Node Failures":

**Backup Node Failures**

If a backup node fails during either "Prepare" phase or "Commit" phase, then no special handling is needed. The data will still be committed on the nodes that are alive. GridGain will then, in the background, designate a new backup node and the data will be copied there outside of the transaction scope.

**Primary Node Failures**

If a primary node fails before or during the "Prepare" phase, then the coordinator will designate one of the backup nodes to become primary and retry the "Prepare" phase. If the failure happens before or during the "Commit" phase, then the backup nodes will detect the crash and send a message to the Coordinator node to find out whether to commit or rollback. The transaction still completes and the data within distributed cache remains consistent.

In your case, all updates for all values in the map should be done in one transaction or rollbacked. I guess that these articles answered your question.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for providing all the information in one page.

Comment: Sorry, I provided you the old link. You can find more articles (including ones from the previous link) here - https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions#section-two-phase-commit-2pc